# How can we see our Winter Bash hat progress?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I've looked through the [FAQ](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/faq).

I checked the "duplicate questions" and they appear outdated.

Previous hat progress was apparently by link http://winterba.sh which now forwards you to http://stackpromos.com/promos/12/winter-bash-2012 which is no longer relevant.

Is there any way for me to track progress of hats in the current Bash much like I can track my current badge progress?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you mean? Like "6 out of 7 votes in the app" sort of thing?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess we have to count to seven ourselves. ;)

Comment: Hi @Catija yes exactly - another example, https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/fascinator I know I've done searches, but I don't know if they have been different days UTC time - some of the hats are more complex than just being able to count to 7 :)

Comment: Well, you know it hasn't been three different days because Winter Bash isn't even two full days old. :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no progress bars for hats and never have been. That's just too much work to incorporate into things and use up resources for an event that only lasts a few weeks and only has a few hats that would benefit from any sort of tracking. A lot of the hats are for a single action, or for a number so low that tracking could easily be done by counting on your fingers.

Comment: thank you! I did find some queries in other questions related to SO badges that maybe can be adjusted for this purpose

Comment: "A lot of the hats are for a single action, or for a number so low that tracking could easily be done by counting on your fingers." "vote 150 times"